# Taxes not applied to products after customer login in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I have two user groups one is default and another is retailers. I have added a product with special price for retailers group. On the front end the taxes are showing up for default users but when a retailers is logged in then special price is showing only, no taxes get applied.

Is there any setting that taxes get applied also for the special and discounted prices?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your Admin/Backend, go to System -> Localisation -> Taxes -> Tax Rates

In your Tax Rates section, go to the specific Tax Rate you have set up already. See if there is a checkbox on for your "retailers" group. You have to make sure you have the tax enabled for each customer group you want to apply it to by marking its respective checkbox.